# EF Core and Pomelo 5.0 - how to query the json column

Tags: json, mariadb-10.3, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm using last version of json implementation in Pomelo 5.0 and configure my maria server to use microsoft json serialisation.

```
  var serverVersion = new MariaDbServerVersion(new Version(10, 3, 0));

    services.AddDbContext<BusinessManagementDbContext>(options =>
    {
      options.UseMySql(databaseConfiguration.ConnectionString, serverVersion, m =>
     {
       m.UseMicrosoftJson(MySqlCommonJsonChangeTrackingOptions.FullHierarchyOptimizedSemantically);
       m.EnableRetryOnFailure();
     });
      
      options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
    });
```

I can save my POCO in my db but when I try to query my data, I get a null object.
Here's my data :
[HeidySQL data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j1S2.png)

My query is pretty simple but I think I'm not using the right way for json query.

```
await Context.ValidatedSaleInvoices.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

It seems like there is no deserialization between my data and my property "Content".

How can I do this ?

Thank you,

***Edit***

My model is :

```
     public class ValidateSaleInvoiceEntity
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ValidateSaleInvoiceContent Content { get; set; }
  }

  public class ValidateSaleInvoiceContent
  {
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; internal set; }

    public string Number { get; internal set; }

    public Address Address { get; internal set; }

    public List<ValidateSaleInvoiceLineEntity> Lines { get; internal set; } = new List<ValidateSaleInvoiceLineEntity>();
  }

  public class ValidateSaleInvoiceLineEntity
  {
    public string Description { get; internal set; }

    public decimal Quantity { get; internal set; } 

    public decimal UnitPriceVatExcluded { get; internal set; } 

    public decimal VatRate { get; internal set; }
  }
```

And my json Result was like this (empty, like there waere no deserialisation: { "BusinessName":"", "Date":"", "Number":"" etc.}

My boss stop my poc about MariaDB Json implementation so I had to go back to this good old friend pure sql column :/ . That's why I haven"t a full json result. Sorry

Comment: Are you trying to get a particular record with the specified ID  and did you parse an available ID?

Comment: I'm trying to get all the json contained into the column with the ID. I'm expecting to have my content parsed, but it don't, all my properties inside have default values but not the value of the database.

Comment: @C.Rozan Please post your model configuration code (Fluent API) for the `ValidatedSaleInvoice` entity and the class used for the `Content` property.

Comment: @C.Rozan Also, please post your complete JSON sample data as text, so it can be used for testing.

Comment: @lauxjpn I edit my post :)

Answer (score 2):

For a property to serialize/deserialize JSON automatically to a POCO, you need to tell Pomelo, that the table column of the property is of the MySQL/MariaDB type `json`:

```cs
public class ValidateSaleInvoiceEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "json")] // <-- this is one way to do it
    public ValidateSaleInvoiceContent Content { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // ...
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ValidateSaleInvoiceEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.Content)
                 .HasColumnType("json"); // <-- this is another way to do it
    }
}
```

Here is a fully working console project:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    // EF Core entities:
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        // Either use this data annotation, or the corresponding Fluent API call (see
        // OnModelCreating), to explicitly mark the column type as JSON.
        [Column(TypeName = "json")]
        public IceCreamDetails Details { get; set; }
    }

    // JSON class:
    public class IceCreamDetails
    {
        public int Kilojoule { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                var connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So68020732";
                var serverVersion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);
                
                optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion, options => options
                        .UseMicrosoftJson(MySqlCommonJsonChangeTrackingOptions.FullHierarchyOptimizedSemantically))
                    .UseLoggerFactory(
                        LoggerFactory.Create(
                            configure => configure
                                .AddConsole()
                                .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                    .EnableDetailedErrors();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>(
                entity =>
                {
                    // Either use this Fluent API call, or the corresponding data annotation
                    // (see the IceCreamDetails class), to explicitly mark the column type as JSON.
                    entity.Property(e => e.Details)
                        .HasColumnType("json");
                    
                    entity.HasData(
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 1, Name = "Vanilla", Details = new IceCreamDetails { Kilojoule = 865, Rating = 9 }},
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 2, Name = "Chocolate", Details = new IceCreamDetails { Kilojoule = 903, Rating = 10 }});
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var iceCreams = context.IceCreams
                .OrderBy(i => i.IceCreamId)
                .ToList();

            Trace.Assert(iceCreams.Count == 2);
            Trace.Assert(iceCreams[0].Details.Kilojoule == 865);
            Trace.Assert(iceCreams[1].Details.Rating == 10);
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the most comprehensive JSON sample code on [our repository](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/14#issuecomment-725257107) (see the `JSON mapping and query scenarios` section).

Comment: I have had the json type in my OnOnModelCreating but I'll try the other way. 
Maybe there's something wrong in my query too :) 
Thank you for your suggestions, I'll try it in an other poc

Comment: Ah, you didn't post any Fluent API code, so I assumed you were using none. If you use the data annotation attribute, it just gets translated to a `HasColumnType()` call internally. They are the same thing. Anyhow, just run the sample code that I provided and ensure that is works as expected on your end. Then compare your code to the sample code to figure out were the actual issue is.